# Once an Android application has an open beta test, can you revert later to closed beta?

Tags: android, google-play, beta-testing

Google has recently introduced new testing features for Android applications, adding the possibility to do open beta and open alpha testing.

Once an application has an open beta test, is it possible later to revert to closed beta testing only? I am trying to plan what type of beta testing to use.